# setting up a friend list in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I want to make a friends list in my online game. I am not sure how to set it up or where to start. The add friends and accept friends part I can handle, but I don't know how to set it up in mysql and php. A list of users (friends) connected to each user or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your friendship relationship is symmetrical, you can either store each pair in a separate record:

```
friend1 friend2
A       B
B       A
A       C
B       D
C       B
D       B
```

and query all `B`'s friends like that:

```
SELECT  friend2
FROM    friends
WHERE   friend1 = 'B'
```

or store the user with the least `id` in the first field and that with the greatest `id` in the second one:

```
friend1  friend2
A        B
A        C
B        D
```

and query `B`'s friends like that:

```
SELECT  friend1
FROM    friends
WHERE   friend2 = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT  friend2
FROM    friends
WHERE   friend1 = 'B'
```

The first option is a little bit more efficient in `MySQL`, and this is the only option if your friendship relationship is not symmetrical (like on `LiveJournal`)

See this article:

- [**Selecting friends**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/07/selecting-friends/)

Comment: Do you need to assign a primary key still on the relationship table?

Comment: @Mike: of course you do, to get rid of duplicates and to speed up searches. The relationship table can also have attributes on its own (like a date of the friendship established etc).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're talking about composite primary keys, right? Both primary keys and both foreign keys referencing back to the "users" table.

Comment: @MikeSanchez: `CREATE TABLE friendship(a INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users, b INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users, PRIMARY KEY (a, b))`

Answer (score 5):

A friendship is essentially a mutual relationship between two people. In database terms it's a many-to-many relationship between two users.

So what you need is a linking table that holds references to two users by ID.

### Example

Users table

```
ID    Username
1     Bob
2     Jim
3     Alice
```

Friends table

```
user1    user2
1        2
2        3
```

This would make Bob friends Jim and Jim friends with Alice.

Comment: Hi @robinjam! Just wanted to check with you regarding this. If my friend list is symmetrical, should it go like this: If 1 is friends with 2 then 2 is friends with one. Creating 2 row entries in the table for their relationship. Thanks!

Comment: Mike Sanchez: The Friends table is modelling mutual friendships, so you'll want 1 row per friendship, not 1 row per person.

Comment: I was going to try and use this kind of set up in a php+mysql environment. Correct me if I'm wrong but with your kind of set up, I would have to use UNION. As opposed to creating 2 entries in the table I can just use a single WHERE user1="1" statement.

Comment: Mike Sanchez: Depends what you're trying to do. Could you open a new question rather than posting comments on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers in this other post here on stackoverflow...some simple but great explanations to accomplishing what you need.

[Facebook database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009025/facebook-database-design)

Answer (score -1):

An alternative would be to set column A as follow:
$checkfriend = (($friend1 $friend2) || ($friend2 $friend1))

Column B as follow:
(friendship accepted or friendship rejected) based on user's choice

Basically have both user1 and user2 in the same column.