# MySQL social friend table structure with friend invite

Tags: mysql

I am trying to design a DB structure for a friends list. I have read some posts and the most simplest is to store each pair in a table as per this post [setting up a friend list in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674005/setting-up-a-friend-list-in-mysql) however I have a different need. My app allows people to invite people which may not yet be users of the app (no registered account yet).

So a scenario would be: User1 installs the app. They invite 10 of their friends to use the app. 5 of those friends are already registered users, 5 are not. For the 5 registered users I was just going to create the friend_relationship table and have:

```
Friend1    Friend2    Confirmed
User1      User2      yes
User2      User1      no
User1      User3      yes
User3      User1      no
...
```

This seems pretty straight forward as I can pull the registered users ID from the user table but stuck on the non registered users.

As I am writing this I thought I could have another table to store the non registered users and put a flag in the friend_relationship table 'registered = yes/no' then when/if the user registers (using the same invite email) update the friend_relationship table to 'registered=yes' and remove the non registered record.

Still unsure if this is the best approach and appreciate the thoughts of pros!

Comment: It seems like a good solution, how will you uniquely identify users, with their email address?

Comment: Yep thats what I was thinking as invites would need to be emailed