# nodejs (expressjs) how to pass information from 2 queries into jade?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

I have a table of users and their information and a different table to keep track of friends: [setting up a friend list in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674005/setting-up-a-friend-list-in-mysql)

I am trying to do something like this using jade, profile.jade:

```
    - each user in users
        h1='Welcome to '+user.username+' profile!'

    - each friend in friends
        p=row.friend2
```

express

```
function select(id, res) {
    connection.query(' SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = "'+id+'" ' , function(err, rows){
        res.render('profile', {users : rows});  
    });

    connection.query(' SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend1 = "'+id+'" ' , function(err, rows){
        res.render('profile', {friends: rows});     
    });
}
```

^ What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Personally I'd use a promise library like [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and it's [`.all()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection.query(' SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = "'+id+'" ' , function(ferr, profile_rows){
 connection.query(' SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend1 = "'+id+'" ' , function(err, friends_rows){
  res.render('profile', {friends: friends_rows, users : profile});     
 })
});
```

This is a simple solution which would make it work, however makes the queries run sequentially hence increasing loading time.