# Store list of values (such as interests)

Tags: mysql, list, database-design

I've got a table of

**Users:** `(ID, FNAME, LNAME, INTERESTS,...)`

plus another table to hold the specific set of INTERESTS they can choose from: Film, TV, Radio, Stage, Standup.

They can have more than one interest, so how can I store this information in the Users INTERESTS's field? Or what is the best alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009025/facebook-database-design

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 9):

It's a many-to-many relationship. You store these by introducing a "join table".

```
Table Users:
-----------
UserID PK
Name
...


Table Interests
-------
InterestID PK
Description.
....


User_interest
-----------
UserID PK, FK
InterestID PK, FK
```

Comment: The column `UserInterestID` in `User_interest` is redundant. The table should have just two columns and its primary key should be `(UserID, InterestID)`.

Comment: sounds good but how to I query the database to bring me a list of a user's interests using this method?

Comment: uhm - if you need to ask, you probably need to read up on SQL, joins, the relational model etc. A good place to start is http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Answer (score 8):

Read about [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in your MySQL book. It's an important topic, so there's probably a large chapter about it.

In short, you remove `interests` and end up instead with a *third* table, like:

```
user_id | interest_id
--------+------------
   1    |     1
   1    |     2
   2    |     1
   3    |     4
```

This gives you your many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Here is a video on database normalization which helped me: https://youtu.be/UrYLYV7WSHM

Answer (score 3):

the best solution to this is to use 3 tables (a third one for storing the connection of interests to useres):

```
user (id, name)
interest (id, description)
user_interest (user, interest)
```

this is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).