# Desgin a Simplified Facebook posting database sschema

Tags: php, database-design, web-applications

I have developed a reduced version Facebook posting database schema.
I'm just wonder whether I am doing it correct or not.
Could some help me take a look and give me some comments?

Condition:

```
      1. Email address can be used for one registration.

      2. Posting is composed of a text and images up to maximum 5.

      3. User can reply to a comment or reply.

      4. Comment can be liked but not be commented further.

      5. A user can only like a comment once.

      6. Post_id is unique.
```

> Registered User (**User id**, User_name, User_email_address, password)
>
> User Profile (**User id**, Picture id)
>
> User’s friend (**User id**, **User id**)
>
> Posting (**Post id**, Post_text_message, User_id, Post_date_time)
>
> Image in post (**Post Id**, **Image id**, User_id)
>
> Image (**Image id**, Image _link)
>
> Comment (**Comment id,** **Post id**, User_id, Comment_date_time,
>   Comment_text_message)
>
> Reply to comment (**Reply comment id**, **Comment id**, **Post id**,
>   User_id, Reply_comment_date_time, Reply_comment_text_message)
>
> Reply to reply (**Reply_id**, **Reply_comment_id**, User_id,
>   Reply_to_reply_date_time, Reply_to_reply_text_message)
>
> Like a posting (**Posting id**, **Like user id**)
>
> Like a comment (**Posting id**, **Like user id**)
>
> Like a reply (**Reply comment id**, **Like user id**)

Answer (score 0):

Are you are expecting a review. I would like to start with some of my suggestions.

- The actions you are listed out here completely depends upon what is your purpose and scope of the application.
- For a simplified **fb** version , my opinion is completely in favour for you.

I would also like to share with you some of the links i came across.

[Facebook database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009025/facebook-database-design)

https://www.quora.com/What-is-Facebooks-database-schema

https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2014/sites/default/files/slides/Percona%20Live%202014.pdf

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship

Comment: yeah, may you do a review on my work?
It is merely my individual work.
I concern on the posting function on in this simplified Facebook.