# Best approach for implementing comments and likes system like Instagram or Twitter

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design, database-normalization

We are designing a database (MySQL) for the course project. This is exactly what we're stuck in: comments and likes system. 
So we have found this question: [Implementing Comments and Likes in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database)

It is beautifully and precisely explained. But every likes or comments has to be a new row. The Instagram's Like button is hit an average of ~4.5 billion times per day. This is too huge for `likes` table. 4.5bx30 days=135 trillion per month! I don't believe they're doing a design that way.

- The Main question that we have in mind: How can we design the most appropriate design structure used by large companies? (Twitter, Instagram, etc.) (Minimal query execution, most optimized, etc.)

That's how we actually thought:

- If someone comment on the post, the JSON will be updated in the comments column. Is this method more efficient than adding a new row for every comment or like?

[image: database_struct]

- We found this class diagram: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120491/5685796
  This design was shared in 2009. If we are doing large projects, does implementing this schema create an optimization problem for us in the future? (Suppose each share comes with 1 million likes and 1 million comments. :))

Edit: We are designing as relational database.

Comment: What's right for Amazon/Facebook/Google is probably not right for you. It is extraordinarily unlikely you'll ever hit anything like 4.5 billion likes a day. You can spend months engineering a massively expensive, overly complicated solution, or you can just do what you need now. That's how all these big sites started - [here's Google's first storage server](https://blog.cartridgemonkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Google2.jpg), for example. http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/voy/museum/pictures/display/0-4-Google.htm

Comment: As for how Facebook does it, probably not in MySQL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra

Comment: I guess it was a misunderstanding, I didn't say it was "wrong". How does it not slow down the table that only multiply by billions of times per day? Even if the distrubuted structure works on thousands of servers, how does the query speed not slow down after months? I asked if it was okay to design it as JSON because I thought of this problem.

Comment: "how does the query speed not slow down after months" The data is distributed, so hundreds of servers may be individually consulting the small portion of data they contain, which is then rolled up into a single result. Again, though, you don't *start* with this - even Facebook likely started with a simple set of `posts`, `comments`, and `likes` table in a traditional relational database. They'll have moved to more complicated solutions *only when it became necessary to do so*. In the case of Cassandra, they **literally had to build the tech themselves**.

Comment: @ceejayoz - The slowdown occurs, when (1) the table/index is much bigger than can be cached in RAM (buffer_pool), and (2) the accesses are scattered (as with uuids or any hash).  The slowdown occurs because of needing to do I/O _instead_ of finding the result in cache.

Comment: @RickJames How do large companies design tables for the comments and likes system? Is it similar to the this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/5685796

Comment: @FurkanTürkal - I added to my Answer.

Comment: @FurkanTürkal - And I added some more -- relating to that link.

Comment: @FurkanTürkal - (I did not work for any of those 'large companies', but for an equally 'large', and older, one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate table for Comments.  It will have the 5 columns you indicated.

Putting things in JSON makes them hard to get to, search, filter on, etc.  Ditto for any kind of array.  You are doing both -- putting an array of JSON objects in a single cell.

Learn about `JOIN` for re-connecting the things I am telling you to separate.

To get into the trillions, you will also need 'sharding'.  But let's not discuss that until after you have gotten into the millions.

(More advice)

The "large companies" have a dataset that is "sharded" across hundreds of servers.  `Comments` are very likely to be in a regular table.  JSON is not likely to be used; especially not for anything to search on or sort on.  JSON is good for miscellany kruft that needs to be saved, but not searched/sorted.

It is really best for you to

1. design and implement *something* (even if it includes JSON);
2. Put in into production;
3. Study the problems that arise;
4. In a few months redesign - be willing to throw away most of the original design.
5. "Rinse and repeat". There are too many hurdles to leap over to get to where the large companies got to after a decade and dozens of engineers.

I can only help you do one iteration at a time.

Likes...  If you are keeping a counter, then do it in a 'parallel' table.  This will lower contention on the main table.  If you are keeping a list of who liked what, then that is a table unto itself.

IDs...  Do not use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a table that has a perfectly good PK.  The main example is any many:many table -- use the composite of the two ids.

Normalize, but don't over-normalize.  This is something that you will begin to understand in my 'step 3', above.

Do *not* use EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schema design.  It does *not* scale well.

Subclassing often gets clumsy.  In that link, they have Photo/Article/Place "is a" Entity.  No.  `Photos` should be its own table with its own columns, quirks, indexes, etc.

Do *not* use any 3rd party software.  OK, you can use it for the *first* iteration of my steps above.  But in step 4, throw it entirely out.  By then, you have been forced to learn the details of MySQL (since the software will fail to fully keep you from needing to learn the details).

Comment: I think, 'sharding' is my keyword that I use to do research. For some reason, I thought it would be more productive to design the comments and likes system with JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information! I'm already starting to research. :)